# multiple independent blog accounts with python based framework

Tags: python, django, django-cms, mezzanine

I am looking for a python based blog/cms application which can work in a multi account environment. Account holders should be able to choose/create their own templates, their content should work in an isolated environment from one another.

Would Mezzanine or Django-cms be able to independently isolate blogs by accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think what you're asking for is called "multiple sites".  it appears in the table at https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/ and for mezzanine is described at http://mezzanine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment.html#multiple-sites-and-multi-tenancy .  similarly, for django-cms it is described at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms/jQNWVos9vg8

both of these seem to be built on the django sites framework - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

this all just from googling - i have no experience on this.  i am answering because i suspect your question will be closed soon, as s.o. editors don't like questions that ask people (or could be interpreted as asking) to recommend things.  so better half an answer now, than none later...

Comment: It is what I was looking for, but I couldn't get the right terminology to look it up in google. Thanks.